# How to advance the consumer offset in a Kafka consumer group to the end?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Is there an **easy** way--using the Kafka REST API--to advance the consumer offset on all partitions in a consumer group to the end of the partition?  Effectively, I want to sometimes skip consuming all remaining messages--for example, if I anticipate re-producing them all.

I know I could retrieve the consumer group, retrieve the partitions, loop through, and seek each one--is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation on [post--consumers-instances-positions-end](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka-rest/api.html#post--consumers-(string-group_name)-instances-(string-instance)-positions-end) you can do that for a `ConsumerGroup` with the following request:

```
POST /consumers/testgroup/instances/my_consumer/positions/end HTTP/1.1
Host: proxy-instance.kafkaproxy.example.com
Content-Type: application/vnd.kafka.v2+json

{
  "partitions": [
    {
      "topic": "test",
      "partition": 0
    },
    {
      "topic": "test",
      "partition": 1
    }

  ]
}
```

Still, you need to know in advance the subscribed topics and partitions of the ConsumerGroup in advance.

### Edit:

> I want to sometimes skip consuming all remaining messages

I see multiple options here but all of them are rather hacky in my point of view and also not using the Kafka Rest API.

#### Option 1

Change the retention time (`retention.ms`) of the topics to a small value (like `1`), wait a bit to let the LogCleaner delete all messages and change the retention time back to normal. Then produce your new alternative data.

#### Option 2

Change the ConsumerGroup names of all your consumers to a new ConsumerGroup (configuration `group.id`) and let the consumers read from the end of the topic by setting `auto.offset.reset=latest`. Then produce your new alternative data.

#### Option 3

Similar to my initial answer use the Kafka tool `kafka-consumer-groups` to manually change the offset of a Consumer Group (e.g. "myConsumer") to the end offset:

```
bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --reset-offsets --group myConsumer --topic myTopic --to-latest
```

Comment: Topics I can handle, but I still have to get the partitions.  Would be cool to have a call to just do all partitions?  Still very helpful.  Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, this seems to indicate that it would push the offset for a certain instance.  Any idea how I would do so for all existing instances?  My use case is that I want all consumers to skip all remaining unconsumed data, for example, when it is invalid and I am about to produce new alternative data to the topic.  Is there a better way?

Comment: Hi @PatrickSzalapski, I have added a few alternatives to my answer on how to deal with this use case.

Comment: Can you help me learn where I can get kafka-consumer-groups?  I have Windows and debian.

Comment: It is a command line tool and should be located in your Kafka installation directory.

Comment: I have not installed kafka as I am on windows.  I am using conduktor and the. Net client.  Maybe I can install the client tools only...do you know how I might?